# Restrict the app for x86 abi in Google Play

Tags: android, x86, google-play

How to restrict the application installation for x86 abi in Google Play?

I split the apk in gradle like this, but x86 users still can download the latest version.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

Comment: Some x86 Android devices might report `armeabi-v7a` as a secondary supported ABI because they have some sort of ARM software emulation layer (e.g. libhoudini). I'm not sure there's anything you can do about that.

Comment: @Michael The problem is that I have 3d-party libs only for arm abi.

Comment: Right, but these x86 device may have support for running your ARM libraries through emulation. How well that actually works is a different matter. I'm just saying that there might not be that much you can do to prevent your app from being installable on those devices.